# Multiple Excel workbooks and 1004 run-time error

Tags: vba, excel

Bumped into run-time error 1004 at line "Set wbForm1Original = Workbooks.Open..."  Would really appreciate some advice.  This routine is to duplicate an original workbook and name the copy of the workbook based on some content in a data workbook, then copy the content of a row in the data workbook into this duplicated workbook. (Do the same for each row in the data workbook: duplicate, name, copy content)

```
Sub createForm()

Dim dirPath As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim file As String
Dim companyName As String
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim wbVendor As Workbook
Dim wbForm1Original As Workbook
Dim wbForm1Company As Workbook

Set wbVendor = ThisWorkbook
dirPath = CurDir()
n = 5

For i = 2 To (n + 1)

    companyName = wbVendor.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value

    file = "177_609 i_" & companyName & ".xlsx"
    filePath = dirPath & "\" & file

    Set wbForm1Original = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user1\Documents\8. Finance\Vendors\177_609 i.xls")

    wbForm1Original.SaveCopyAs filePath
    Set wbForm1Company = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

    Workbooks("Vendor.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & CStr(i)).Copy _
        Workbooks(file).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I13")
    Workbooks("Vendor.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & CStr(i)).Copy _
        Workbooks(file).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I14")
    Workbooks("Vendor.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & CStr(i)).Copy _
        Workbooks(file).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I15")
    Workbooks("Vendor.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & CStr(i)).Copy _
        Workbooks(file).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E16")
    Workbooks("Vendor.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & CStr(i)).Copy _
        Workbooks(file).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J16")
    Workbooks("Vendor.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & CStr(i)).Copy _
        Workbooks(file).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M16")

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it probably opened by another person? Or already opened?

Comment: @Vityata - I stumbled onto your website earlier... quite an impressive collection!  :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg - thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the workbook in a loop without closing it. Thus, it does not like it. Either close the workbook, before openning it again or put the openning outside the loop, like this:

```
Set wbForm1Original = Workbooks.Open("C:\...\8. Finance\Vendors\177_609 i.xls")
wbForm1Original.SaveCopyAs filePath
Set wbForm1Company = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

For i = 2 To (n + 1)
'further code...
```

Comment: @Olive Also, it's generally a good practice not to have spaces in your workbook names (eg. `177_609 i.xls` should be changed to `177_609_i.xls` if possible)

Comment: Olive - you are welcome. Take a look at the comment of @Rawrplus as well, having a space in the filename is sometimes a bad idea.

Comment: Just realised the wbForm1Original is solved, but the second one wbForm1Company needs to remain in the loop because it depends on the rows on loop.  After adding wbForm1Copy.Close SaveChanges:=True at the end of the loop, I still received 1004 error.

Comment: @Olive - check whether `wbForm1Copy` is opened, before trying to close it. Btw, I do not see a variable named `wbForm1Copy` are you sure it exists?

Comment: Thanks, the second one is solved.  It was related to copying it as xlsx instead of xls which was the original format.  Also, I have updated the filename.  Thank you all.